# hapi.js cors with auth

Tags: javascript, hapi.js

Put together the below.

```
server.route([
  {
    method: "POST",
    path: "/authorize",
    config: { 
      auth: false,
      cors: {
        origin: ['*']
      }
    },
    handler: (request, reply) => {
      ...
      reply.redirect(redirectUrl)
    }
  }
])
```

I want to use with client-side JavaScript browser fetch API. The `cors` part is necessary to avoid using the `no-cors` mode for `fetch` and to get a non-opaque response.
If I use only 'auth`in the config section or only`cors` they work fine, but together hapi complaints that the configuration is wrong.

Why is that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

inside `config` object you cannot use key `cors`. for correct configuration you have to put `cors` key inside this like this

```
server.connection({
  port: dbConfig.port,
  routes: { cors: true } // set cross origin by hapi inbuilt property
   // tls: tls
})
```